# Edit elements inside website and iframe with content script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm working on my extension and I have huge problem with one website. When I'm trying to log for example   `$("#tinymce > p").textContent` which is part of iframe I receive error `"Cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent')"`. Unless I inspect this iframe, then I receive proper message. I found out that I need to specify which part of website I want to edit in my contentscript but I have no clue how to do that. There are two elements that I really need to edit. First is `gsft_main` and `incident.u_html_description_ifr`. Even if I  select `gsft_main` I can't log content of iframe and when I select `incident.u_html_description_ifr` I can't log content of main. What is worth mentioning even after page reload I need to select `gsft_main` to avoid error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2LFr.png

Answer (score 0):

After hard times I found solution that allows me to access wanted selector

```
var y = document.querySelector('#gsft_main').contentDocument
var x = y.getElementById("incident.u_html_description_ifr");
var z = x.contentDocument;
var xx = z.querySelector("#tinymce > p").innerText;
```